# Data-Virtualization issue with SurfaceScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, data-visualization, wpf-4.0, surface-toolkit

I'm in a situation where I'm using an ItemsControl with a SurfaceScrollViewer bound to an [AsyncVirtualizingCollection](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344) and all of the data is being requested. I'm aware that it's due to the ItemsControl request all of the data but I'm not sure how to get around this.

I've tried the AsyncVirtualizingCollection bound to a ListBox and it works fine and I'm now attempting to having it bound to a SurfaceListBox but the problem persists.

Any ideas of how to overcome this?